# How to call ajax call to form submit from ASP.NET MVC/ jQuery Dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

When user clicks on a hyperlink , I want to run a background process. Before I run that I want to ask user's permission using jQuery dialogbox (form). When user clicks "ok" on the form , I want to run the action using jQuery ajax. If process fails then I want to update that popup with "Error". How do I do this in asp.net MVC using jQuery AJAX. Below is the code I tried

Here is my MVC Ajax begin form code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "eProcess" }, new { id = "eProcess" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("eID", eId);                                                                                  
    @Html.Hidden("processName", "processName");                                                                                                                                                
    <div class="hide" id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
        Are you sure you want to update this record? <br />                       
        <input type="button" value="Hit" id="btnHit" />                    
    </div>    
}
```

and below is my dialog code

```
$("#dialog").dialog
({
    dialogClass: "ee-detail-info",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {

        $("#btnHit").click(function () {

            $('#processName')[0].value = processName;
            document.forms.eProcess.submit();  

        });
        }
```

});

I even tried using the .ajax method but still its doing full post back. I double checked my jQuery files. They are linked correctly on the page.

```
$("#eProcess")[0].submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#eProcess")[0].action,
        success: function (res) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
});
```

### Update

I got it working with your solution. I had bug in my code.

Comment: return false...or preventdefault?

Comment: Yes I put return false, no change in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I double checked my jQuery files. They are linked correctly on the page.

Make sure that you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script after jquery.

If this is the case you don't need to be manually be subscribing to any .click events. Simply leave the `Ajax.BeginForm` to send the AJAX request.

And if you don't want to rely on the `Ajax.BeginForm` then simply write a normal form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "eProcess" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("eID", eId);                                                                                  
    @Html.Hidden("processName", "processName");                                                                                                                                                
    <div class="hide" id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
        Are you sure you want to update this record? <br />                       
        <input type="button" value="Hit" id="btnHit" />                    
    </div>    
}
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        dialogClass: "ee-detail-info",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#dialog').on('submit', '#eProcess', function() {
        // here you could set the value of the the hidden field
        // if you wanted to pass some additional information
        // to the controller

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $('#eProcess').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. I tried using both approach. Still getting same result. My ajax call is triggering and also my page postback is triggering.